# phpmailer working for .doc, IMG files but not with pdf attachments

Tags: phpmailer

I am trying to make  HTML contact form with an upload file option which should allow only .doc, .pdf and image files with limited file size(<2MB). I tried the below code. It is working fine for DOC and IMG files but the email is not sent if I am uploading PDFs.

I am using AJAX in HTML file and passing to PHP file.

Code:

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$msg = '';
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {
    // First handle the upload
    // Don't trust provided filename - same goes for MIME types
    // See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php#114004 for more thorough upload validation
    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        // Upload handled successfully
        // Now create a message
        //require '../vendor/autoload.php';



//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "exampl@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = 'password';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$message .= "Name: ".($name)."\n";
$message .= "Email: ".($email)."\n";
$message .= "Message: ".$_POST['message'];



$mail->addAddress("example@gmail.com");


$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
$mail->Subject = "Message from website";



$mail->Body = $message;
// $mail->MsgHTML($body);
// $mail->AddAddress($address, $name);

$mail->AddAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES['userfile']['name'], $encoding = 'base64');


if($mail->Send()) {
  echo "Message sent!";
} else {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

} else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I'd guess this is going wrong before it ever gets as far as attempting to attach it. When you submit a PDF, does it appear in the `$_FILES` array? You're also using a **very** old version of PHPMailer, and you've based your code on an old example, so upgrade now. Also, test your PHP code separately from your JS, otherwise it's hard to tell where the problem lies.

Comment: I am new to PHP. I have tested this code without JS and the same issue. Help me to test if it appears in $_FILES array. Thanks.

Comment: Add `var_dump($_FILES);` at the top of your script.

Comment: I echoed var_dump($_FILES) right after require_once('class.phpmailer.php'); but not echoing. I could see the file uploaded in URL.This is the URL after form submission - http://localhost:8080/p/main-att.html?name=cvxv&email=xyz%40gmail.com&MAX_FILE_SIZE=100000&userfile=resume-sample.pdf&message=xcvxcv.

Comment: If you're seeing it in the URL, it means you're using a GET request, and you can't use GET requests for uploading files; you need to use a POST method.

Comment: added POST method